# How to load markers from xml file for google maps

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to recreate the code from this page:http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerhider/markerhider.htm
so that i will be able to run it using xampp localy. Right now i have created 2 files, the first called markerdata.xml which has the following code:

```
    <markers>
<marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Buddha Thai & Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bars"/>
<marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bars"/>
<marker name="Mama&apos;s Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bars"/>
<marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bars"/></markers>
```

and the second called try.php which has this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example</title>
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=ABQIAAAAjU0EJWnWPMv7oQ-jjS7dYxSPW5CJgpdgO_s4yyMovOaVh_KvvhSfpvagV18eOyDWu7VytS6Bi1CWxw"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
var customIcons = [];
customIcons["restaurant"] = iconBlue;
customIcons["bars"] = iconRed;
var markerGroups = { "restaurant": [], "bars": []};
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.614495, -122.341861), 13);
    GDownloadUrl("markerdata.xml", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    });
  }
}
function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
  var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
  markerGroups[type].push(marker);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  });
  return marker;
}
function toggleGroup(type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
    var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
    if (marker.isHidden()) {
      marker.show();
    } else {
      marker.hide();
    }
  } 
}
//]]>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Arial, sans serif" onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="float:left; width: 300px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
   <div id="sidebar" style="float:left; width: 120px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black">
   <input type="checkbox" id="restaurantCheckbox" onclick="toggleGroup('restaurant')" CHECKED />  
    Restaurants
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="barCheckbox" onclick="toggleGroup('bars')" CHECKED />  
    Bars
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

while running this code using Google Chrome i only see the first 4 markers and the check box for restaurants works fine, but i can not see the markers for bars and if i change the category of one marker from bars to restaurant in the xml file when I reload the page it does not show on the map. And in all the other browsers no marker shows. Can anyone see any mistakes in the code?

Comment: You are using the deprecated [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), that has been replaced by a wrapper for v3; any new code should be developed in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: ok then how should I change the above code so that it will work?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3 (referenced on the link to the documentation for v2), [example of loading markers from XML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) [from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm)